# VisualStudioCode IDE Red Triangles in HTML Markup Editor

Tags: visual-studio, ide

What do these red triangles represent, missing closing tags?  I checked all over the [VS Code docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs), nothing documents these visual cues.

[image]

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Probably you didn't searched all the pages :)

*"A red triangle indicates where lines have been deleted"*

From: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/versioncontrol#_gutter-indicators